# Hanging figures in Times

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums, times

I would love to see hanging figures by using the `times` package, but according to docs it is not possible. Typing `texdoc times` in console I was informed that this package is obsolete and it's recommended to use `mathptmx`. I realized that `mathpazo` has `osf` option, but there is nothing like it for `mathptmx`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Hanging (oldstyle, lowercase) figures with Times are an anachronism; in my opinion they would look like a wristwatch in the movie “Ben Hur”. The font was designed with lining figures in the Thirties.

Comment: Thanks egreg. I was in fact totally wrong about and did not considered the recent history of this font. By the way wikipedia is enough to (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman)

Answer (score 2):

The TeX Gyre Termes font (a replica of Times) offers oldstyle figures. Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}

This is TeX Gyre Termes.

0123456789

\end{document}
```

[image]