# Old style numerals using times and mtpro2

Tags: oldstylenums, mtpro, times

I am trying to use old style numerals with the `times` package for fonts in text mode and `mtpro2` package for fonts in maths mode. I would like to be able to use old style numerals in just a few places in the main body of the text using a command something like `\oldstylenums{}` for example.

If I load the `txfonts` package and use `\oldstylenums{}` I get old style numerals in Times font in the main body of the text but the `mtpro2` fonts in maths mode are replaced by those of `txfonts` which I do not want.

If I load the `oldstyle` package and use `\textos{}` I get old style numerals in the main body of the text but they are in Computer Modern font.

Is what I am asking for possible?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % If utf8 encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English please
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{times} % Use Times font in text mode
\usepackage[zswash]{mtpro2} % Use MathTime Professional 2 fonts in maths mode

%\usepackage{txfonts} % Use \oldstylenums{} for old style numerals
%\usepackage{oldstyle} % Use \textos{} for old style numerals

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

Old style numerals using Times font here
\oldstylenums{01234567890}. 

Normal lining numerals used otherwise 01234567890.

Normal lining numerals used in math mode
\begin{equation}
\zeta(x) = \int^{56789}_{01234} \frac{dx}{e^x - 1}   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I said elsewhere, old style figures in the Times font are just like wristwatches in the movie “Ben Hur”, an anachronism.

Comment: Does [Hanging figures in Times](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119033) (where @egreg made the comment mentioned above) help?

Comment: No as I am using TexLive. I also do not want all numerals within text mode to appear in old style, only those numerals I chose to select.

Answer (score 1):

The `mtpro2` package is not available at CTAN, so I wasn't able to test my suggestion thoroughly. However, if you replace the `times` package with `tgtermes`, the `\oldstylenums` macro works without the need to load the `txfonts` package, and so the math mode font provided by `mtpro2` should be unaffected.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgtermes}

\begin{document}

Old style numerals using Times font here
\oldstylenums{01234567890}. 

Normal lining numerals used otherwise 01234567890.

\end{document}
```